# Updating Shopify Theme with GitHub Integration

Tags: git, github, shopify, themes

I'm guessing my understanding of git is all wrong. I have my Shopify theme files in a GutHub repository. The developer of the theme released a new update and I want to apply my current live theme settings to this new theme update. Here's what I can't figure out how to do:

1. How do I create a new branch "updated-theme" and upload the new theme files since a branch always reflects the source branch (current live theme)?
2. How can I run a diff on the newly updated theme to see what changed from the current live theme?
3. What is the best workflow for copy/pasting the current live theme settings to the newly updated theme and then merging that newly updated theme with the current live theme?

I ended up creating a totally new repository for the newly updated theme and just manually copy/pasting the current live theme settings over. Then I made the newly updated theme branch the live theme.